# Sorting php codeigniter sort by date for blog page

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting

i am having a little issue, with a blog page, the blog post are in ascending order i should have "the latest should be first" descending order
this is the code i have try for the blog post page

```
<div class="imgContainer m-b-10 foroverlay0305"><img alt="company logo" class="" src="<?php echo $blogImage;?>"><span><?php if(isset($category_blog_title)){ echo $category_blog_title;} ?></span></div>
  <h2><?php if(isset($row->title)){ echo character_limiter($row->title, 15);} ?></h2>
  <p style="color:#340000;"><?php if(isset($row->post_date)){ echo $row->post_date;} ?></p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: And your question is?  You haven't included any sorting code.

Comment: @LorandPopaAved probably should have included the DB query you are using pull in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are pulling results out of a database, and in CodeIgniter, when you have a query and you need it sorted, use the order_by method. The first parameter is the field you want to sort by, and the second parameter is the sort direction:

```
// For blog posts sorted by post_date in ascending order
$this->db->order_by('post_date', 'asc');
```

or

```
// For blog posts sorted by post_date in descending order
$this->db->order_by('post_date', 'desc');
```

See the details in the CodeIgniter user guide: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results